# How to perform select where in array column - Symfony3 + Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have created an entity with Symfony3 where i set an field column in database as Array.

Symfony saved to DB registers like:

```
id | name    | roles
01 | Raphael | ["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"] 
02 | Jose A. | ["ROLE_ADMIN"] 
03 | Marcos  | ["ROLE_USER"]
```

How can i perform an select with Doctrine just for the `ROLE_ADMIN` or just `ROLE_USER`?

I`ll need to create search for many other situations... but this one is the easiest to explain...

Hope you understand my situation... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this syntax:

```
$formData = $form->getData();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$usersRepository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Usuario');
$qb = $usersRepository->createQueryBuilder('r');
$qb->select('a')
    ->from('AppBundle:Usuario', 'a');

foreach($formData as $key => $value) {
     foreach($value as $k => $item){
         $qb->andWhere("a.$key LIKE :it_$k")
             ->setParameter("it_$k", '%'.$item.'%');
     }
}
$result = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```